# C++ linker flags in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm compiling a C++ program and have been getting the following error message:

```
undefined reference to 'pthread_mutexattr_init'
undefined reference to 'dlopen'
undefined reference to 'dlerror'
undefined reference to 'dlsym'
undefined reference to 'dlclose'
```

To resolve the error for `pthread` I added the following linker flag to my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
if (UNIX)
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
endif (UNIX)
```

This resolved the `pthread` error. To resolve the `libdl` error I went ahead and modified it to the following.

```
if (UNIX)
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread -dl")
endif (UNIX)
```

This gave me a warning

```
unrecognized gcc debugging option: l
```

I modified it to the following

```
if (UNIX) 
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-dl")
endif (UNIX)
```

And got back all the error messages together with

```
unrecognized gcc debugging option: l.
```

Do I miss how to set linker flags in CMake? What exactly am I doing wrong? I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 x64.

Comment: tried `target_link_libraries(yourtarget pthread dl)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the modern canonical CMake method for `pthread` and `dl`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(my_pthread_dl_project)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads)
add_executable(myexe source.c)
target_link_libraries(myexe 
  Threads::Threads 
  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Comment: Why should this be preferred than @Akira's approach?

Comment: It is not as platform specific and has no bad habits.

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following way instead of overwriting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
project(FooProject)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include_dir)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source_dir FOO_SOURCES)

add_executable(foo ${FOO_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(foo pthread dl)
```

The `set` command overwrites the variable. If you use it like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
```

the old concent of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` will be replaced. To append something to a variable, you should use the `set` command as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
```

Comment: Why are you using `aux_source_directory` here?

Comment: @SirDarius, just for the sake of completeness. I use `aux_source_directory` for all projects to collect source files.

Comment: I'm mentioning this because the documentation says explicitely that it is not good practice and this command should only be used for explicit template instanciation. Explicitely listing source files is the preferred way in CMake.

Comment: @SirDarius, thanks for the clarification. This is my bad habit then which may originating from Qt Creator's CMake project template.